# Eigenvalue and eigenvector implies that matrix $A$ satisfies $a_{ik}=a_{ij}a_{jk}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following [theorem (2.2)](http://books.google.com/books?id=wct10TlbbIUC&lpg=PP1&hl=eng&pg=PT50#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The author says the 'if' part is obvious so the proof was not given.

Theorem 2.1 above says that every positive $n \times n$ matrix whose elements satisfy the property $a_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kj}$ ($i,j,k=1,2,...,n$) can be written in the form of ratios, just like matrix $W$. I believe there's a mistake in theorem 2.1 - it says matrix has ratio form $A=(w_i w_j)$. I guess it's supposed to be $A=(w_i / w_j)$.

Back to theorem 2.2 - could anyone provide a proof of the 'obvious part', i.e. given that if $w$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$ (equal to dimension of matrix) of matrix $A$, then matrix $A$ satisfies the property $a_{ik}=a_{ij}a_{jk}$ (definition of a consistent matrix). Also check my latest comment.

Comment: The statement doesn't really make sense to me. It's saying "The matrix of ratios is consistent if and only if _____". But if I understand correctly, a matrix of ratios is ALWAYS consistent. So the "if" part is not just obvious, it doesn't have any content.

Comment: I've decided to come back to this - I guess we should understand it that way: say we have a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfying $Aw=nw$. It follows that $A$ is consistent, i.e. for every element of $A$ it holds that $a_{ik} = a_{ij}a{jk}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** For all $i,j,k=1,\dots,n:$

$$a_{i,k}a_{k,j} = \frac{w_i}{w_k} \cdot \frac{w_k}{w_j} = \frac{w_i}{w_j} = a_{i,j}.$$